# How to buy a weekly ticket for Munich public transport?

Tags: public-transport, munich

I often travel to Munich and figured it would be more cost effective to get a weekly ticket. The [official website](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-fares/tickets/frequent-travellers/isarcard/index.html) mentions you can do so at most ticket machines by purchasing a ticket called the *IsarCard*. However when I enter my destinations on the ticket machine, I'm only offered to buy single tickets or strip tickets. So my questions are:

1. How do I get the MVV ticket machines to sell me a weekly ticket?
2. Can I also do so on the *DB Navigator* app somehow?

Comment: Ticket machines are on all S-Bahn and U-Bagn stations and have English options. Note that by 'cancel the ticket' they mean 'validate the ticket'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you try to purchase from the MVV ticket machine, you should look for options for buying an Isarcard and not try to enter your destination. 
If you are trying to purchase from a DB ticket machine, you should select the MVV tab, but I'm not sure if there is an option to buy the Isar card from here.
But all S,U stations have the MVV ticketing machines and you should be able to buy the Isarcard from there.

With the Isarcard option, you get an option to buy a weekly ticket for the zone you would want the ticket to be valid. More info [here](https://www.mvg.de/tickets-tarife/vielfahrer/isarcard.html).
I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4qDV1XwV0g) video which shows the step-by-step procedure to buy a weekly ticket. :)

It is unfortunately not possible to buy the Isarcard online. But you can purchase them either at the ticket machines of MVV or the MVV ticket centers in Hauptbahnhof/ Ostbahnhof etc.

Comment: There **is** an option of buying Isar card from DB ticket machine.